# Is dynamic div loading taking more time than static div in HTML?

Tags: html

In my application, a large number of divs is dynamically rendered in an HTML page through the use of JavaScript. In fact, there are more than 100 dynamically created divs. Loading the content from server side, it is taking more time to load dynamic divs than static divs. How can I reduce the time it takes to load dynamic divs? This is the sample code I am using:

```
var ul_slide = document.createElement('ul');
var slide_div = document.createElement('div');
slide_div.setAttribute("class", "slide");
for (var i = 0; i < data.arrayItems.length; i++) {
    alert(data.arrayItems.length);
    var postId = data.arrayItems[i].postId;
    var tag = data.arrayItems[i].tag;
    var li_slide1 = document.createElement('li');
    var img_link1 = document.createElement('a');
    var linka = "#" + postId;
    img_link1.setAttribute("href", linka);
    img_link1.setAttribute("class", "click");
    var img_slide1 = new Image();
    img_slide1.style.width = "159px";
    img_slide1.style.height = "100px";
    img_slide1.setAttribute("src",data.arrayItems[i].url);
    img_link1.appendChild(img_slide1);
    li_slide1.appendChild(img_link1);
    ul_slide.appendChild(li_slide1);
    slide_div.appendChild(ul_slide);
    div.innerHTML = "";
    div.appendChild(slide_div);
}
```

Comment: What are you using to load 'dynamic' divs? php? javascript? - please show your code.

Comment: 100 dynamic DIV's with dynamic content will take too time to load. Better try using some cache techniques. It will save your loading time for sure. :)

Comment: content for dynamic divs is different for different users and the content having images videos etc. how can i store it in cache